# How can I get/write info about/in comments to telegram channel?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api, telegram-api

Is there a way to get information (ids, etc) about comments inside a channel post in telegram from telegram API ? Or is there an API method to write to the post comments? Could you provide some examples if this is possible?

Thanks